# Past and Present Perfect tenses in one sentence

Tags: sentence-construction

Should I use "have" or "had" in the sentence below?
Can I use Past Tense and Present Perfect Tense in one sentence?

> Salary was paid to you base on declaration you have done.

One more example:

> I was asked to do this by John and accordingly have done.

Comment: The meaning of the sentence is not entirely clear.  Can you explain what you mean in different words?

Comment: I want to say that salary which employee has received was base on the declaration he has made in system

Comment: Stangdon i have added one more example

Answer (score 1):

I would not use either perfect tense.  To me, it sounds more natural to say

> **Your salary was paid to you based on the declaration that you made.**

That uses only the simple past, because everything that we are talking about is something that has already happened.

Let's break down this sentence:

> *Your salary*...

We can't just say "Salary was"; *salary* is a "count noun", so it has to be *a salary*, or *the salary*, or *your salary*.

> Your salary *was paid to you*...

We say *was paid* because this happened in the past, and we are using the passive voice.

> Your salary was paid to you *based on*...

Something *is based on* something else.

> Your salary was paid to you based on *the declaration*...

Like "salary", *declaration* is a count noun.  "A declaration", "the declaration", "your declaration", etc.

> Your salary was paid to you based on the declaration *that you made*.

You *make* a declaration.  Because this making of the declaration was in the past, *you made the declaration*.  Therefore, it is *a declaration that you made*.  We're using the simple past, because the making of the declaration is a thing that is finished and done, and we already knew that, so therefore the simple past is the most logical choice.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. But can we use the sentence as i written.

Comment: In a word, no. Stangdon carefully went through several ways your first sentence is wrong. The second sentence is correct tense, but is not idiomatic. Try "and I have done it." the word "accordingly" could be added but does not add any clarity of meaning. Any reader can discern that you did it because John asked you to .